# Localization of DataAnnotations for data validation

Tags: c#, localization, community-toolkit-mvvm, displayname-attribute

I'm using `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm`.

My class is defined in the following way:

```
public partial class User : ObservableValidator
{
    ...

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyDataErrorInfo]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredAttribute_ValidationError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DataAnnotations))]
    [Display(Name = "Name_Field", ResourceType = typeof(Fields))]
    private string name = "";

    ...
}
```

Where `typeof(DataAnnotations)`and `typeof(Field)`are the types of the resources (resx) where I keep the translations.

I have a `TextBox` bound to the `Name`, so that if I type something into it and then deleted, it shows the error: `The 'Name' field is required`.

Now I added a button that once pressed changed `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` between `pt-PT` and `en-US` and that changes all the text in the app between those two languages... Except for `Display Name`.

If culture is set to `pt-PT` before any validation and a validation occurs, the error reads: `O campo 'Nome' é obrigatório`, but if I then change the culture to `en-US`, the message now reads: `The 'Nome' field is required`.

Converselly, if culture is set to `en-US` before any validation and a validation occurs, the error reads: `The 'Name' field is required`, but if I then change the culture to `pt-PT`, the message now reads: `O campo 'Name' é obrigatório`.

So apparently the culture used to translate `Display Name` is set the first time the resource is used and is kept until application restart, while the translation of `Required` (and similar annotations like Phone, Email, etc) change when I change the UI culture.

Q1: Why is the translation of `Display Name` work differently?

Q2: How can I get the translation of `Display Name` to adapt to UI Culture changes, like other annotations do?

Thanks in advance